# FontForge Python appendSFNTName issues

Tags: python, opentype, fontforge

I'm a Python beginner and I'm trying to create small python script which renames FontFiles SFNT attributes (Family, SubFamily, FullName) using FontForge python bindings.

The script listens for `raw_input`, then prepare the strings, and use FontForge methods to apply changes.

But I've encountered quite a strange issue, when passing a `variable` (type str) instead of directly a `'string'` in the method parameters, the change is not applied, but only for one of the SFNT attribute.

I know that FontForge create a tuple from the SFNT tables. FontForge provides a method to change a tuple `font.appendSFNTName(language,strid,string)`.

Change is applied for instance for **SubFamily**, but not for **Family**.

After checking if it was a issue with unicode, it doesn't help neither.

Sadly my skills in C are not that good, to check if there is some strange casting done in the Python bindings.

Am I totally missing something here?

Here's the code extract:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import fontforge 
import sys  

fontfile = sys.argv[1]

try:
    font = fontforge.open(fontfile)
except EnvironmentError:
    sys.exit(1)

family_name = u' {}'.format(raw_input('Family name: ')
                      or 'Default Family Name')
style_name = '{}'.format(raw_input('Style name: ')
                     or 'Default Style Name')
full_name = family_name + " " + style_name

# Apply PostScript names
font.familyname = family_name
font.fullname = family_name + " " + style_name
font.fontname = full_name

# Force SFNT Table
font.appendSFNTName('English (US)', 'Family', family_name) # here
font.appendSFNTName('English (US)', 'SubFamily', style_name)
font.appendSFNTName('English (US)', 'Fullname', full_name)


print "Family is", font.sfnt_names[1]
print "SubFamily is", font.sfnt_names[2]

# Save and create a new font
font.generate(font.fontname + '-new.otf', flags=('opentype'))
```